# Error while linking shared library FFMpegJNI to android project

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have built an ffmpeg module for all the architectures, but when I try to build project to run it on emulator (x86 architecture) i get an error, indicating that the files for x86 architecture are incompatible with elf_i386. The same is for other architectures, i get the error that the files are incompatible. What can i do in this case?

```
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library E:\android_studio_projects\projects\IPTVPlayer\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1h3dp6s4\obj\x86\libffmpegJNI.so
FAILED: E:/android_studio_projects/projects/IPTVPlayer/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/1h3dp6s4/obj/x86/libffmpegJNI.so 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\volos\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=i686-none-linux-android30 --sysroot=C:/Users/volos/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libffmpegJNI.so -o E:\android_studio_projects\projects\IPTVPlayer\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1h3dp6s4\obj\x86\libffmpegJNI.so CMakeFiles/ffmpegJNI.dir/E_/media3/media-release/libraries/decoder_ffmpeg/src/main/jni/ffmpeg_jni.cc.o  -landroid  E:/media3/media-release/libraries/decoder_ffmpeg/src/main/jni/ffmpeg/android-libs/x86/libswresample.a  E:/media3/media-release/libraries/decoder_ffmpeg/src/main/jni/ffmpeg/android-libs/x86/libavcodec.a  E:/media3/media-release/libraries/decoder_ffmpeg/src/main/jni/ffmpeg/android-libs/x86/libavutil.a  C:/Users/volos/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/i686-linux-android/30/liblog.so  -latomic -lm && cd ."
ld: error: E:/media3/media-release/libraries/decoder_ffmpeg/src/main/jni/ffmpeg/android-libs/x86/libavcodec.a(mpegaudiotabs.o) is incompatible with elf_i386
```

Comment: Are you targeting x86 (32 bit) or x86_64 (64 bit)? Because you seem to mix up both architectures which will nit work.